# Change content of binary file

Tags: tcl

I want to change the content of a (large) binary file without reading and writing the whole file content. This is what I tried out:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
set f [open MyFile.txt w+]
fconfigure $f -translation binary
foreach c [split "MyText is ABC" ""] {
    puts -nonewline $f $c
}
seek $f 2 "start"
foreach c [split "Name" ""] {
    puts -nonewline $f $c
}
close $f
```

I create a file and change *Text* into *Name*. That works fine.

But if the file already exists and I want to change *Text* into *Name* with the following program

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
set f [open MyFile.txt w+]
fconfigure $f -translation binary
seek $f 2 "start"
foreach c [split "Name" ""] {
    puts -nonewline $f $c
}
close $f
```

it doesn't work. The reason is that *open filename w+* truncates the file. Does someone knows how to change the content of an existing binary file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use `w+`; what's the problem? Did you read the `open` manual page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a large binary file and you're not wanting to change the size much, it's best to use the `open` mode-string `r+b`; `r+` is read-write without truncation (`w+` is read-write with initial truncation, `a+` is read-append, so every write goes to the end of the file) and `b` means “binary mode”. Then use `seek` to move to where you want to write and `puts -nonewline` to write the binary string out. Binary strings can be made in a number of ways, but key ones are `binary format` and `encoding convertto`.

```
# Open the file to write
set f [open "foobar.bin" "r+b"]

# Pick your offset to write to
seek $f 10240

# Writes a pair of 4-byte integers in little-endian form
puts -nonewline $f [binary format "i2" {123 345}]

close $f
```

The above little script updates the file `foobar.bin` to have a particular 8 bytes at 10kiB in. Those eight bytes are the little-endian 4-byte words for 123 and 345.

Comment: The one occasional downside to `r+` is that it errors if the file doesn't exist. If that's a problem, you need to use POSIX flag modes. See the `open` manual page for details.